# fade out/in images by clicking corresponding span

Tags: jquery, onclick, fade, html

I have six images that I want to fade in and out, according to an onclick function of corresponding numbers. The function is triggered by spans that appear as the numbers 1 to 6.

the html:

```
<img id="prC1" class="swpr" src="Img/SW_prC1.jpg" height=360px width=520px >
<img id="prC2" class="swpr hidden" src="Img/SW_prC2.jpg" height=360px width=520px >    
<img id="prC3" class="swpr hidden" src="Img/SW_prC3.jpg" height=360px width=520px >    
<img id="prC4" class="swpr hidden" src="Img/SW_prC4.jpg" height=360px width=520px >    
<img id="prC5" class="swpr hidden" src="Img/SW_prC5.jpg" height=360px width=520px >    
<img id="prC6" class="swpr hidden" src="Img/SW_prC6.jpg" height=360px width=520px >   

<span id="loadswimage1">1</span>
<span id="loadswimage2">2</span>
<span id="loadswimage3">3</span>
<span id="loadswimage4">4</span>
<span id="loadswimage5">5</span>
<span id="loadswimage6">6</span>
```

the css:

```
.hidden {
display:none; }
```

the script:

```
$(function(){
$('#loadswimage1').click(function(){
    $('.swpr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#prC1').fadeIn('slow'); });  })  });

$(function(){
$('#loadswimage2').click(function(){
    $('.swpr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#prC2').fadeIn('slow'); });  })  });

$(function(){
$('#loadswimage3').click(function(){
    $('.swpr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#prC3').fadeIn('slow'); });  })  });

$(function(){
$('#loadswimage4').click(function(){
    $('.swpr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#prC4').fadeIn('slow'); });  })  });

$(function(){
$('#loadswimage5').click(function(){
    $('.swpr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#prC5').fadeIn('slow'); });  })  });

$(function(){
$('#loadswimage6').click(function(){
    $('.swpr').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#prC6').fadeIn('slow'); });  })  });
```

As you can see, my strategy for the jquery is to fade out all the images by class, and then fade in the desired image using a call back function.

When I implement the script, the images do change, but after the first fades out the new image appears quickly and then fades in again.

The main thing I want is to be able to click on any span number at any given moment to fade out / in to the desired new image.

Where is this little glitch coming from? 
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

While adeneo's solution is correct as well, I would go with this approach, because it's independent of element DOM-positions.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="swpr">
    <img id="prC1" src="Img/SW_prC1.jpg" height="360" width="520" alt="1" />
    <img id="prC2" src="Img/SW_prC2.jpg" height="360" width="520" alt="2" />    
    <img id="prC3" src="Img/SW_prC3.jpg" height="360" width="520" alt="3" />    
    <img id="prC4" src="Img/SW_prC4.jpg" height="360" width="520" alt="4" />    
    <img id="prC5" src="Img/SW_prC5.jpg" height="360" width="520" alt="5" />    
    <img id="prC6" src="Img/SW_prC6.jpg" height="360" width="520" alt="6" />   
</div>

<span data-id="1">1</span>
<span data-id="2">2</span>
<span data-id="3">3</span>
<span data-id="4">4</span>
<span data-id="5">5</span>
<span data-id="6">6</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.swpr img+img{ display:none; }
```

**JS:**

```
$('span').click(function(){
    $('.swpr img').not(
        $('#prC'+$(this).data('id')).stop(true,true).fadeIn()
    ).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/EfA9w/

Comment: yes that does the trick perfectly, only, the first image is hidden when the page is loaded.

Comment: @LauraMaasry is it hidden on your site or on my demo page as well? Could be that your html is different than on my demo. Or you're using a very old browser which doesn't support the [CSS Adjacent-Sibling Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) which i used. You could try `.swpr img{ display:none; } #prC1{ display:block; }` instead of `.swpr img+img{ display:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be all you need :

```
$(function(){
    $('[id^="loadswimage"]').on('click', function(){
        var idx  = $(this).index('[id^="loadswimage"]'),
            curr = $('.swpr:visible');

        if ( curr.index() !== idx ) {
            curr.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('.swpr').eq(idx).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xG9p/1/)

This uses the index of the spans to fade in the image with the same index, another solution would be to use a class or data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it ain't working is because .hidden class is the one holding the display:none; property and basically what fadein does is change this value to block.

Look like your code is trying to change display property of your element. Hidden class still forces or overrides the sane property with none.

Try this,

$('#prC1.hidden').fadeIn();